# gradle 2.14 and sonar 5.6 integration

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a little problem with integration gradle 2.14 and sonarqube 5.6 LTS.
My gradle.build look like below:

```
  repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
          }
    }


 dependencies { 
     'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2'
     ....
   }

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

and gradle properties:

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.login=sonar
systemProp.sonar.password=sonar
systemProp.sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
systemProp.sonar.projectKey=some_project...
systemProp.sonar.ws.timeout=60
```

or even when I change on  latest version plugin like this :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

I got exception (gradle with mode --info):

```
:sonarqube FAILED
:sonarqube (Thread[Task worker,5,main]) completed. Took 1.421 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the [documentation of the SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html), the official and supported way to activate SonarQube analysis in your Gradle build file is simply:

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}
```

I've just tested and it works smoothly. So you should probably just simplify your build file to just have these lines.

Comment: It works !
Indeed, this resolved my problem. I was not aware that this is necessary if I defined before :

 dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
}
and 

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"


Thanks for help :)

Comment: Glad that it helped @przodownikPracy! Can you please accept the answer so that it appears as the good solution to this question. Thanks!